# jQuery UI Tabs and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

With a custom jQuery UI file stored in location `root/a/b/c/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom.min.js`, how can I do `$('#ui-grid').tabs();` using RequireJS? the main jQuery file is already defined in RequireJS as jquery.

Am new to RequierJS. I've searched the manual, read various posts on the internet and Stackoverflow but none seem to ask or answer a question like this. So I tried various solutions but failed including the following:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "ui": "/a/b/c/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom.min"
    }
});

define(['jquery','ui'], function() {
    $("#ui-grid").tabs();
});
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a solution. If jquery is already defined in RequireJS, then this is enough to get it to work:

```
require(['jquery', '/a/b/c/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom.min.js'], function ($) {
    $("#ui-grid").tabs();
});
```

Hope it helps someone.